# Can you explain how this JavaScript code gets executed step by step?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Obviously, a beginner here.

1st option:

```
var myArray = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

for (a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {
  var output = 0;
  output += myArray[a];
}
console.log(output); // Output is 10 in this case.
```

2nd option:

```
var myArray = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

var output = 0;

for (a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {
  output += myArray[a];
}
console.log(output); // Output is 30 in this case.
```

So, my question is - why the output is 10 when "var output = 0" is inside the function, but when it is outside the output is 30?

Comment: _"...is inside the function..."_ - There are only loops in your example, not functions. And `var` has no block scope, therefor the `var ...` is in both cases not "in" the loop ([var - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var))

Comment: there is no function here. You have an array and a loop. that loop runs 5 times, that means the code inside the brackets run 5 times because the length of the array is 5. you declare a variable output and set it to 0, then you add the current value of the loop to it, its 2 so the output is 2. in the next roun you declare output again and set it to 0 so its 0, then you set the current value witch is 4. that goes up to the last round where you declare output to 0 then assigning the last value of your array to it witch is 10 and it outputs 10

Answer (score 0):

The first approach sets `output` to 0 then adds 2, then it **sets it to 0 again** then adds 4, then it **sets it to 0 again**, and so on.

The second approach sets it to `0` then adds 2, then adds 4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First code

```
    var myArray = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

    for (a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {
      var output = 0;
      output += myArray[a];
    }
    console.log(output); // Output is 10 in this case.
```

Above code has incorrect syntax because of using not correct variable scope and may get errors in some cases.

In this case it works and Output is 10 because in each loop times its value reset to 0 because of this command is put in each loop

```
    var output = 0;
```

As a result when you print it, it gets final result 10

Second code out put 30 is quite clear, I think no need further explain